# Clearance login and login redirect breaks after upgrading from Rails 6 beta1 to Rails 6 beta 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, clearance, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using the [Clearance gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/blob/master/NEWS.md) for authentication on an app that I started new with Rails 6 beta 1. Everything was working fine, but when I tried to upgrade to Rails 6 beta 2.

I've also tried the latest stable version of Clearance as well as Clearance 2.0.0.beta1 and I have the same problem.

Here are the [notes on what changed](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2019/2/22/zeitwerk-integration-in-rails-6-beta-2/) between Rails beta 1 and beta 2.

Here are the commits between beta 1 and beta 2.

I'm having trouble figuring out which of these might have broken my Clearance login though.

I can verify in the console that the users are getting created by the Clearance Sign up form, so it just appears to be the login.

I did switch my routes from `get '/login' => 'clearance/sessions#new', as: 'sign_in'` to `get '/login' => 'sessions#new', as: 'sign_in'`, but switching that back .

Any pointers on [what change](https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/v6.0.0.beta1...v6.0.0.beta2) between Rails beta1 and beta2 that might be causing this error would be much appreciated!